# Reveal GCS bucket at specific date and time

Tags: google-cloud-storage

Having a Google Cloud Storage bucket I would like to reveal it (make it public) at specific date and time. How can it be achieved?

I have tried the permissions of bucket only to find out that with principal `allUsers` I cannot use any condition.

Another way that comes up is to script Google Compute instance with a startup script together with Google Scheduler, this however has a unpredictable delay which is my purpose cannot tolerate.

So is there any other way? I do not necessarily need to use GCS, any other service that will allow me to reveal a folder/files at specific time should be enough.

Comment: If you don't want to preserve the existing bucket permissions when you make it public, you can use directly Cloud Scheduler to perform the update directly in Cloud Storage API. Else, you need a function that read the existing permisions, preserve them by adding allUsers as object Viewer, and then send the new IAM policies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can execute your [function that makes objects public](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/making-data-public#code-samples) in Firebase Cloud Functions with [`functions.pubsub.schedule().onRun()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/schedule-functions):

> In Cloud Functions for Firebase, scheduling logic resides in your
> functions code, with no special deploy-time requirements. To create a
> scheduled function, use `functions.pubsub.schedule('your schedule').onRun((context))`.

Comment: I used PHP Cloud Function + Cloud Scheduler... works as expected but it is still a bit long to setup and test :-/